# I'm Still receiving a MisMatchException with a try and catch, any ideas?

Tags: java, try-catch

It works how I want it to, except when I try to type 'exit' to close the program. It then gives me a `MismatchException` even though I have a try and catch.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Student {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Enter the number of students that you wish to be part of the module register: ");
        
            int numofstudents = input.nextInt();
        
            try{
                if (input.nextLine().equals("exit")) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }       
            catch (InputMismatchException IME){
                /*3*/
                System.out.println("\nNot a number or an integer!\n");
                continue;
            }
            finally{
                String[] names = new String[numofstudents];
                int[] array = new int[numofstudents];
                for(int i = 0; i < numofstudents; i++) {
                    System.out.print("Enter the student's name: ");
                    names[i] = input.next();
                    System.out.print("Enter the student's module: ");
                    array[i] = input.nextInt();
                }
            
                selectionSort(names, array);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
             }
         }
    }

    public static void selectionSort(String[] names, int[] array) {
        for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            String temp;
            int currentMax = array[0];
            int currentMaxIndex = 0;
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (currentMax > array[j]) {
                    currentMax = array[j];
                    currentMaxIndex = j;
                }
            }       
            if (currentMaxIndex != i) {
                temp = names[currentMaxIndex];
                names[currentMaxIndex] = names[i];
                names[i] = temp;
                array[currentMaxIndex] = array[i];
                array[i] = currentMax;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: You're calling `nextInt()` *before* your `try` block...

Comment: *Tip: Try to write pretty code by using proper indentations.*

Comment: Btw, the `finally` block is usually only used for closing a stream or connection or something similar, not to have the main part of the code.. Also, note that the code in the finally block will still be run even with the continue in the catch.. It will always go to the finally after a successful try or a failing catch, except in a few very rare occasions (like System.exit and alike).

Answer (score 1):

You ask for module input (`array[i] = input.nextInt();`) in the `finally` block, which does not have a try-catch block.

It executes after the try-catch finishes.

So, it will not catch any exceptions occurring in the finally block.

Also, here : `int numofstudents = input.nextInt();` You ask for input outside the try-catch block, and hence it does not catch the exception.

One solution would be to put the try-catch block on the complete  code, i.e, outside your while loop.

Comment: okay thanks for the help, im new to java so pretty unsure on what to do. what do I need to change?

Comment: @PeteD Instead of calling `nextInt()` and `nextLine()`, you should call only `nextLine()`. Then you have to check if it is a word or try to parse it into number (`Integer.parseInt(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(true) {

        boolean status = true; //represents the status of the process   

        System.out.print("Enter the number of students that you wish to be part of the module register: ");

        int numofstudents = input.nextInt();

         try{

         if (input.nextLine().equals("exit"))
         {System.exit(0);}          

         status = true;

         }catch (InputMismatchException IME){
             /*3*/        System.out.println("\nNot a number or an integer!\n");
             status = false;
                             continue;
         }

        finally{

             if (status==false) {
    String[] names = new String[numofstudents];
    int[] array = new int[numofstudents];
    for(int i = 0; i < numofstudents; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the student's name: ");
        names[i] = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the student's module: ");
        array[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
   selectionSort(names, array);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
             }
   }}
```

the thing is finally block will be called even there is a no exception.
you need to handle the exceptions inside the finally block too .bt i have restricted the finally block getting called everytime with the help of a boolean value. this is very bad coding practise you might need to replace the whole code with a different approach.